# How to automatically adjust spaces to make columns in Notepad++

Tags: text, notepad++, letter

I have two columns separated by `:`.

```
'col2': 'str', 
'col3': 'float', 
'col4': 'float'
'DBN': 'float', 
'School Name': 'float', 
'Category': 'float', 
'Year': 'float', 
'Total Enrollment': 'float', 
'#Grade K': 'float', 
'#Grade 1': 'float', 
'#Grade 2': 'float', 
'#Grade 3': 'float', 
'#Grade 4': 'float',
```

I want to automatically add spaces so resulting text is:

```
'col2':              'str', 
'col3':              'int', 
'col4':              'float'
'DBN':               'str', 
'School Name':       'str', 
'Category':          'str', 
'Year':              'int', 
'Total Enrollment':  'int', 
'#Grade K':          'float', 
'#Grade 1':          'float', 
'#Grade 2':          'float', 
'#Grade 3':          'float', 
'#Grade 4':          'float',
```

I am looking for solution in Notepad++, but if you know other tools for this task, please also share them.

Comment: You should modify your post to list all the notepad++ plugins you've researched and tried. If you haven't done that research, you should give it a whirl.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

TextFX doesn't is outdated and doesn't work on current version of Notepad++

Here is some effort to make it work and probably source code source code is working, but binaries are not available:

https://github.com/PhilR73/NPPTextFX

---

Thanks to suggestion by Jeff Holt I easily found solution: plugin TextFX.

screenshots from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5cQ-1JnsW_g

Before:

[image: how to do this]

After:

[image]